# How to add multiple folders into one zip file via ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to copy two folders with lot of files via ADF piepline from my source to my storage account every 20 min. My source: SFTP server in bianary and target Blob storage

The structure of source data would be:
`
Folder1
Subfolder1
file.dat
file.dat
file.csv

```
  Subfolder2
   file.txt
 Folder2
   Subfolder1
   Subfolder2
```

`

When I use ZipDeflate(.zip) my piepline keeps running for more than 20 min. I just wonder if there is a way to have the .zip out put based on the trigger time including two folder in one pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use ZipDeflate(.zip) my piepline keeps running for more than 20 min.

This depends on the number files and size of the files that you have in the source. If you are not getting the output zip file, make sure you set the source binary dataset compression to **None** and target binary dataset compression to `ZipDeflate(.zip)`.

As you mentioned, your pipeline will run for every 20 minutes but pipeline run time duration is taking more than the interval time.

> I just wonder if there is a way to have the .zip out put based on the trigger time including two folder in one pipeline.

In this case, you can use `Self-dependency tumbling window triggers` **which runs the pipeline only after the previous trigger run is completed.**

Create the trigger of your pipeline like below.

[image]

- Here, my trigger name is `trigger1`. Set your interval and in the `Advanced`, click on **New** and give the same trigger.
- As we are using self dependency triggers, we need to give the Negative values to the Offset.
- Give the **Offset** in this format `-0.00:20:00`. As your interval is 20 minutes give the same as offset. Here, my interval is 5 minutes, so I have given the offset according to it.

In my pipeline, I have given `360` Seconds i,e. 6 minutes. So, the pipeline will run for 6 minutes which is greater than the interval of the trigger. But due to the Self-dependency trigger, it will only start the pipeline only after the previous run completed. You can see the same in the below pipeline runs.

[image]

Refer this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tumbling-window-trigger-dependency#tumbling-window-self-dependency-properties) to learn more about this.